# Column name in mysql - IN clause not working

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `t1` and `t2`.

Can I use code like below in the where clause?

```
t2.id in (t1.itemOption)
```

Where `itemOption` contains comma separated values like 1,2,3...

ID will be 1 or 2.

Comment: I think it should be like `t2.id in (select itemOption from t1)`.

Comment: So `itemOption` column is in varchar type right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by following

t2.id in (select **yourcolumn** from t1)

Answer (score 0):

Use [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

```
FIND_IN_SET(t2.id,t1.itemOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column `itemOption` is like comma separated, then just concat all the values in `itemOption` column and use that in `FIN_IN_SET`.

**Query**

```
select * from t1 
where FIND_IN_SET
(
    t1.id,
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(itemOption SEPARATOR ',') from t2)
);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af7c4/1)